# Calculate percentage overlap for two ranges vertica sql

Tags: sql, vertica

Suppose I have two ranges: a and b below.

[image]

My goal here is not just calculate whether there is any overlap between a and b, but to calculate the percentage overlap.

For example record 1 would have 0%
record 2 would be 100% given that 37-42 is a subset of 36-42, 
record 3 would be 4/6 given that it's missing 41 and 42, but contains 37,38,39, and 40.

Is there an easy way to do this in vertica?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `greatest()` and `least()`:

```
select least(least(hours_to_b, hours_to_a) - greatest(hours_from_b, hours_from_a)), 0) /
       (greatest(hours_to_b, hours_to_a) - least(hours_from_b, hours_from_a)) as overlap_ratio
```

EDIT:

Oh, you want the overlap with "a" within "b", not the overall overlap of the two.  This is similar:

```
select (least(least(hours_to_b, hours_to_a) - greatest(hours_from_b, hours_from_a)), 0) /
        (hours_to_b - hours_from_b)
       ) as overlap_ratio
```

Comment: hmm I'm getting an error upon execution here?  The denominator doesn't make sense. (b-a, a) what kind of operation is this?  Additionally, the numerator parentheses don't line up